# Ошибка работы бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Проблема следующая: при запуске бот работает нормально некоторое время, но потом, когда к нему не обращаешься минут 10-15 вылетает ошибка:

> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал
> существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Не подскажете в чём проблема? Запускаю у себя на компе, может, если выложить на хостинг, не будет вылетать ошибка?

Comment: А дайте код, плз, который проводит к ошибке

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего заключается не в коде.

1. Возможно нестабильное подключение к интернету
2. Возможно были проблемы со стороны телеграмма

Попробуйте сделать эхо бота (к примеру вот)

```
import config
import telebot

#config-это предполагаемое название файла в котором лежит token вашего бота     

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

И проверьте такая ли же будет ошибка, если да , то проблема в подключении , если нет , то проблема в одной из функций вашего бота